# aucRoc and roc functions in the caret R package

Tags: r, machine-learning

I am reading the `caret` R package's paper on the Journal of Statistical Software [link](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v28/i05/paper), and on pages 15-16, the author introduced the use of calculating ROC and AUC. However, since version 5.13-037 these functions are no longer available (see [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/news.html)). I think they're convenient functions but not sure why they're deprecated.... Any suggestions on alternative approaches/functions for ROC and AUC? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pROC` package for example:

```
library(pROC)
data(aSAH)
# Basic example with 2 roc objects
roc1 <- roc(aSAH$outcome, aSAH$s100b)
```